# PDFBox PDPageContentstream.setTextMatrix() making text disappear

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am converting POSPrint-data to a PDF. At one Point i need to strech the Text over 2 Lines, but with the width of the normal text. I'm trying to archive that like this:

```
CONTENT.beginText();
Matrix textMatrix = new Matrix();
textMatrix.scale(1f, 2f);
CONTENT.setTextMatrix(textMatrix);
CONTENT.newLineAtOffset(50, 50);
CONTENT.setCharacterSpacing(line.getLineSpacing());
CONTENT.showText(restOfLine);
CONTENT.endText();
```

sadly this results in the text not showing up at all. If i remove the lines for adding the textmatrix, or setting the matrix scale values to 1 this workes without any problem:

```
CONTENT.beginText();
Matrix textMatrix = new Matrix();
textMatrix.scale(1f, 1f);
CONTENT.setTextMatrix(textMatrix);
CONTENT.newLineAtOffset(50, 50);
CONTENT.setCharacterSpacing(line.getLineSpacing());
CONTENT.showText(restOfLine);
CONTENT.endText();
```

or

```
CONTENT.beginText();
CONTENT.newLineAtOffset(50, 50);
CONTENT.setCharacterSpacing(line.getLineSpacing());
CONTENT.showText(restOfLine);
CONTENT.endText();
```

Does anybody know why this happens?

I use PDFBox 2.0.25

Comment: Is it possible that this depends on the used font? I also tryed using a built in font (Helvetica) but that also didn't work...

Comment: Just a thought... you're scaling Y, could it be that the text now appears at position 100 ? And that this is outside of your receipt?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Good idea, but im just scaling the text itself, not the position or anything, i also testet it and it would still disappear.

Comment: Try playing around, `textMatrix.scale(1f, 1.1f);` what happens now?

Comment: I just ran your code pieces (only added enough frame to make it runnable). In the result the text from all three variants was visible: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRP9B.png). Thus, there is something special about your whole setup you don't tell us.

Comment: That confirms my suspicion, that the position is influenced as well.

Comment: @LinusHoja *"but im just scaling the text itself, not the position or anything"* - by the way, that is wrong. Setting the text matrix to a scaling matrix not only scales the text, it also scales text coordinate changes. Just like Tilman mentioned before...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You are right, i just saw that it works with 1.1f but it is shifted up a lot, do you have any idea how to keep the bottom left corner at the same location while scaling the height?

Comment: @mkl ok. If i just scale it by 1.1f it will be very high up, so i cant see it and it probaply gets more, is there a way to prevent this to happen?

Comment: Ty dividing the Y value passed to `newLineAtOffset` by the scale.  (Is this a really tiny tiny receipt that you're printing on?)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Its not that tiny, but im inverting the coordinates, because i have to print from top to bottom. Ill try your idea of dividing Y.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Dividing Y by the scale worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are scaling the TextMatrix, also the position of the matrix is affected. To fix this unwanted behavior of moving the scaled text, you have to divide the textposition also by the scale.

```
CONTENT.beginText();
Matrix textMatrix = new Matrix();
textMatrix.scale(1f, 2f);
CONTENT.setTextMatrix(textMatrix);
CONTENT.newLineAtOffset(50, 50/2f); //devide y position by scale
CONTENT.setCharacterSpacing(line.getLineSpacing());
CONTENT.showText(restOfLine);
CONTENT.endText();
```